# Unminimized source for JavaFX dtjava.js?

Tags: java, javascript, javafx

For use with JavaFX, is the the unminimized source for http://java.com/js/dtjava.js available somewhere, similar to http://java.com/js/deployJava.txt?

Comment: http://java.com/js/dtjava.txt works.

Answer (score 3):

[Unminimized dtjava.js source for Java 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/modules/fxpackager/src/main/resources/resources/web-files/dtjava.js) is available from the [open-jfx](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx) source repository.

Comment: Links provided are now dead.  Here's my best guess: [Unminimized dtjava.js source for Java 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/fxpackager/src/main/resources/resources/web-files/dtjava.js) is available from the [open-jfx](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/) source mirror repository.

Comment: Thanks for comment tunabot, I updated the answer to link to use the live links you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent online service for this - http://jsbeautifier.org/ just paste the minified code and click. There is also an in-built formatting feature in Komodo IDE.

Comment: The formatting is not the only issue. The internal function and variable names have also been obfuscated. I need a pointer to the original source before it was minimized. For the previous incarnation of this code, http://java.com/js/deployJava.js, Oracle offers the unminimized version at http://java.com/js/deployJava.txt. There does not appear to be any such animal for http://java.com/js/dtjava.js.

Comment: It has got the option 'Detect packers and obfuscators' and I don't think there is any tool which can rename the function and variable names to improve understandability. Unless some Oracle employee sees this and decides to share the unminimized source for dtjava.js online, I don't see any way of you getting your hands on it.

Comment: I wonder why the unminimized source is posted for deployJava.js but not dtjava.js...