# Can not run Java Applets in Internet Explorer 11 using JRE 7u51

Tags: java, c#, internet-explorer, applet, jnlp

Today I updated my Java version to 7u51. After the installation, I cleared Java Cache, browser's Cache, and logged into a secure website that uses an Applet to provide certain additional services to the user.

The applet is not working anymore. I accessed http://www.java.com to check the Java version detected in Internet Explorer, and the java website says:

```
We are unable to verify if Java is currently installed and enabled in your browser.
```

[image: Internet Explorer 11 and JRE 7u51 can not verify Java version]

Other browsers can check Java, and the mentioned applet works as expected:

[image: Google Chrome and Firefox can verify Java after the update to 7u51]

As the applet works as expected in other browsers, I can assume the problem is not the Applet nor its deployment files/processes, but the compatibility of JRE 7u51 with IE 11. I would like to know if there is any workaround for this.

As additional measure, I used the java.com tool to uninstall any previous and unsecure JRE version (using Google Chrome). After double checking IE 11, I can see the Java Addons enabled and versioned to 7u51:

[image: IE 11 Java addons are enabled and up to date]

I know IE has been improved; even so, we recommend to our customers to use Google Chrome or Firefox as these browsers have proven to be more compatible with our web applications. Unfortunatelly, we can not force our customers to use certain browser due to the common organizational restrictions about programs usage, etc.

---

**Update (01/20/2014):**

The following screenshot shows Internet Explorer 11 with Compatibility View configured for "java.com". It doesn't fix the problem in this case.

[image: IE11 with Compatibility View doesn't fix the problem]

Comment: I've seen something that is worth to share: I have 2 PCs, both running Windows 8, and both have the latest Java update. Both had the same problem with Internet Explorer 11. After one of them was rebooted, Internet Explorer 11 started to work fine with the latest Java update. A friend wuth Windows 8 updated his Java version too and tested the application in IE 11, and he has the same issue. It seems a Reboot is required to allow IE to work with the latest Java version.

Comment: Please enter that comment as an answer instead.

Comment: Does the same thing in Windows 7 and XP.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problems with IE11 and new Java.
Try to add your site to compatibility view. 
You can find here how to do it.

[How to enable compatibility view in Internet Explorer 11](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-enable-compatibility-view-in-internet-explorer-11-ie11/)

You can try now if it works or not.
After that you can remove site from compatibility view and it should also run.

Comment: I've updated my question's content, to show if the "Compatibility View" fixes the problem. Still no luck.

Comment: Adding the Website to the Compatibility List worked for me (in Win7 x64 and java 7u51)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Java 7 u51.
Only after I reset Internet Explorer it work again, Java was enabled in browser etc.

Internet options -> Advanced -> Reset...

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of applets changes significantly with update 51. It's going to be a confusing couple of weeks for RIA developers. Recommended reading: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, that link has information about the new rules to package and deploy RIAs; fortunately the Applet I mentioned in my question seems to satisfy these instructions, as it works with Chrome and Firefox as expected.

The problem mentioned in my question is related to Internet Explorer, to be precise, version 11, on Windows 8 and 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

We see the same problem with Java 7u51, IE11 and Windows 8.1.  As detailed at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/windows-81-ie11-java-7u51-combination-doesnt-work/24af818d-7196-4dd5-96f5-9c0c65223744 and http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2014-January/010048.html and in a bug report submitted to Oracle on 17 January 2014 we find that all is OK until you agree to Java making changes to your system after installation.  Once you allow the post-installation permission, Java is disabled.  Other than constantly fighting off permission requests, the only workarounds we've found are to use a different environment: browser (use Firefox or Chrome), OS (use Windows 7) or Java version (use a Java 8 build).

Comment: Another maneuver that gets Java 7u51 to work on Windows 8 is running IE11 as an administrator.  Of course this is impractical for regular use, but it is useful information in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I've tried the re-booting approach without success.  Instead, the killing of access to Java seems to come consistently after agreeing to the post-installation User Account control request.

Comment: The "Run as Administrator" solution works!. That should help someone how needs Java and has admin rights on his/her PC. To bad for controlled users who are required to work using IE, and has no admin rights.

Comment: With the "Run as Administrator" approach you keep getting bugged with Oracle security dialogs every time you open the browser and on many page changes.  It is a clunky workaround, but it is useful in localizing the problem.

Comment: The Java 8 workaround continues to work for applets on the Web but now seems no longer to work for local applets.  This is all very brittle, and it seems surprising that Oracle would not have tested this configuration, which represents the default environment on the current version of Windows.

Comment: Since there is now a release version of Java 8, I tried Java 8 update 5, and the problem is fixed.  I haven't tried the current version of Java 7 (update 55), but getting going with Java 8 seems like the preferred solution anyway.

Thanks to all who helped get this problem known and solved.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Control panel.
2. Double click on Java.
3. Go to Security tab.
4. Change security from high to medium.

Your applets will run.

If they are still not running then you have to add that website name in exception site list of Security tab of Java in Control panel.

Answer (score 1):

I know Mickey S. solved his issue with Java 8, but Pavel S. was on to something.  If you're working locally with an applet, setting your Intranet Zone to Low security and then setting Java security in Control Panel -> Java -> Security setting to Medium from High *does* solve the problem of running local applets with Java 7u51 (and u55) on Win 7 with IE 11.

(Specifically, I have a little test tool for barcode generation from IDAutomation that is crafted as an applet which wouldn't work on the above config, until I performed the listed steps.)

Answer (score 1):

I've just resolved the problem on two PCs (Win 8 64-bit with IE10; Win 8.1 32-bit with IE11). With Java 7 Update 67 both cases (same with update 65 and, probably, others).

In my case, it was caused by java ssv, which first requested admin rights, then Java stopped working because it messed something using them.

So, my resolution was:

1. Reinstall java. No reboot required, but close browsers beforehand. Also, it's not required to uninstall it before running installer (I didn't).
2. On 1st (or 2nd) launch of IE, privilege elevation will be prompted for Java SSV. If denied, it will pop up again. Multiple times. Important here is to **deny them all**.
3. To stop these prompts, disable Java SSV helpers (both of them) in Add-Ons or when IE prompts about startup times.
   [image: IE Add-ons manager, Java Plug-In SSV helpers disabled]

After that, http://www.java.com/verify/ prompts to run Java (twice, 1st time IE, 2nd time Java itself) and, when allowed, says everything is OK.

(will give more screenshots if anyone will ask)

Answer (score 0):

Its not about security settings .. its the UserAgent in IE11 ( in IE11 its Trident while all previous versions of  MS IE were MSIE ) so I suppose that Java deployment tool cannot recognize new baby of MS .. and send you back to install Java ..

I already ask if there is any temporarily solution till Oracle guys make new release

[JavaFx web not working with Internet Explorer 11 with JRE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136098/javafx-web-not-working-with-internet-explorer-11-with-jre7/21146769?noredirect=1#21146769)

update:

btw applet is working at least on the oracle test java page : http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp
I just uninstall all JAVA from PC then reinstall latest version and disable then enable "Java(tm) Plug-In 2 SSV Helper and Java(tm) Plug-In SSV Helper " @ manage add-ons. before testing java on web. and it works ..

so I think its JavaFX not applet .. 
since JavafX is using dtjava.js while webstart(applet) using deployJava.js.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I've solved them using `embed` tag instead of `object`.
I'm deploying applet using `JQuery` and:

- `embed` works on IE 11, Firefox 26.0,
- `object` works on Firefox 26.0, Chrome 32, (on IE 11 was about 10 second delay after each page reload) and
- `applet` works on Firefox 26.0, Chrome 32.

I put draft of my script bellow:

```
var baseurl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "//";
var common = 'id="appletid"'; // and more
if (priv.IsIE()) {
    var embedTag = '<embed ' + common +
    ' code="main.java.MyApplet.class"' +
    ' name="' + appletName + '"' +
    ' codebase="' + baseurl + 'Applet"' +
    ' archive="Applet.jar,jna.jar"' +
    ' scriptable="true"' +
    ' mayscript="true"' +
    ' cache_option="Plugin"' +
    ' codebase_lookup="false"' +
    '></embed>';
    appletHtml = embedTag;
} else {
    var objectTag = '<object' + common + '>' +
    '<param name="java_code" value="main/java/MyApplet.class" />' +
    '<param name="mayscript" value="true" />' +
    '<param name="scriptable" value="true" />' +
    '<param name="cache_option" value="Plugin" />' +
    '<param name="codebase_lookup" value="false" />' +
    '<param name="java_codebase" value="' + baseurl + 'Applet" />' +
    '<param name="cache_archive" value="Applet.jar,jna.jar" />' +
    '</object>';
    appletHtml = objectTag;
}
$('body').append(appletHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue that impacted all my browsers.  After completely uninstalling all my JREs and JDKs then startig from scratch, I ran into the same issue.  I'm running Win 7 pro 64 bit.

I detailed out the solution here ([Why does Java 7 fail to Verify after successful JRE installation - Java 7 not running my any browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667848/why-does-java-7-fail-to-verify-after-successful-jre-installation-java-7-not-ru))

but basically I added this "**-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true**" to my vm args (set in the Java Control Panel, under Java tab / View) and that solved the issues I was facing... seems like a hack but I guess the latest JRE does not handle IPv6 type requests properly

Answer (score 0):

Update deployJava.js.

Our site uses a local copy of deployJava.js; updating it to the latest copy has fixed this issue in IE11. (We will probably just start using the web version of deployJava.js instead of a local copy).

However, a (very) similar problem persists for our Safari users.

Answer (score 0):

Once Java(tm) Plug -In 2 SSV Helper was incompatible
Above solution did not work for me.
 
I solved it with the below instruction. 
1. Go to IE settings 
2. Internet options
3. Select Advanced tab
4. Scroll down to Security
5. Uncheck “Enable Enhanced Protected Mode”
6. Click OK and restart the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me.

Go to RUN and type gpedit.msc then completely disable Onedrive. Have you noticed that the problem only existed after the last large download from Microsoft? It contained this package. I also removed it from the Start menu.

This appears to be the cause of the issue. Something to do with downloading temporary files, which of course an applet is.

Once done everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem recently on IE11 with Windows 7.
Applets worked fine before but they stop working from one day to another.
I solved it adding the applet sites to trusted sites and config this with low security level.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved my java install issue on Win 7 64-bit running IE11.

Even though I installed the latest Java (65) via a java auto-update prompt, tried a verify java version and java failed to run, shut down all IE instances, failed to run verify again, shut down all running programs, failed to run verify again, rebooted, failed to run verify again, re-installed 65 again (shutting down the browser manually as it downloaded), and finally verify ran. What a pain.

The message I kept receiving was "The page you are viewing uses Java ..."; e.g. https://www.java.com/en/download/help/ie_tips.xml. I do use sleep mode on my desktop and I believe that this is probably the major issue with install and IE with its "clever" integration into the OS and explorer/desktop. I thought the government told them to not do that. I've had issues with CD-ROM drive disappearing and other unexplained periodic issues; all cured after a full reboot. They are infrequent, so I live with them for the convenience of faster startup times.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a client's pc in IE 11 with Java installed. It worked fine in Chrome, but wouldn't work in IE. After several days of TS, I just tried unchecking ActiveX Filtering in settings->safety. Now Java works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java Control Panel, under the Security tab, uncheck "Enable Java content in the browser" and Apply it.  Then re-check it and apply again.  This worked for me, and I had been struggling with this issue for days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 7 64-bit, I would strongly suggest you download the 64-bit Java installer. There is no sense in downloading the x86 installer on an x64 based OS.

That corrected the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue is cropping up again using the Windows 8 / IE 11 combination with the new version of Java (1.8.0_31).  The installation seems to work, but after installing Java via the Java Control Panel Update tab, every time you run a Java applet you are told your version of Java is outdated, but when you follow the prompts to again update, you are told your version of Java is newer than the one on the web.

As with a previous iteration of such problems, what worked for me was, after installation, unchecking "Internet Options | Security | Enable Protected Mode", running a Java applet and then re-checking it and everything is fine.

Do people at Oracle not test on Windows 8 with IE or does this only happen for people with particular extensions enabled?

As before, this problem didn't happen on Windows 7, but there I noticed that the SSLv3 changes now prevent you from running a local applet in Internet Explorer unless you remove that line from the java.security file.  But this problem doesn't happen on Windows 8, so it is not clear what is actually happening.

If Oracle doesn't make the update process less rocky, people won't update.  I've seen many people lately using 2009 versions of JRE 1.6.  That is the sort of situation that often doesn't end well.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8.1 Users.... there is a **little** note on the java download site which says:

"Downloading and installing Java will only work in Desktop mode on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1. See the Java on Windows 8 FAQ for more detailed information."

Unfortunately, "Desktop mode" is **not** the default mode in Windows 8.1. After installing java and wasting 2hours trying to get java working with IE11, I went back to oracles site...paid a bit more attention to that warning!! switched to Desktop mode, and reinstalled java... hey presto it worked.

Furious, that java download does not work with the default config of Windows 8.1, don't know who to be more angry with? Oracle or Microsoft? ( or me for skimming over the warning..)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with Java 8u31 and IE10, it didn't see Java until I did 2 things:

- delete temp files (all kinds)
- reset all zones to default (Options -> Security -> ...)

Answer (score 0):

Also experienced issues with Java the last 2 weeks no longer working in IE 11 under Windows 7 x64  (reverted to Chrome where it DID work)

I had to go through (ALL) the following steps in order to restore Java operation:

1. Try and install latest Java => Error was produced 'The installer cannot proceed with the current Internet Connection setting'
2. Hit 'Retry', and the installer started working
3. Java 8 update 40 was installed successfully, however Java still doesn't work in IE (after closing IE / reboot)
4. Removed older/outdated versions (either using the Oracle-Java tool or through Install/Uninstall programs). In my case, I was able to remove old version 7 update 71.
5. After another attempt to close IE completely and restarting Windows did not resolve the issue (as before, testing Java operation using the Oracle-Java online tool failed to work and even failed to produce the 'grey box' that is always shown (in spite of the fact that the Java-plugins are loaded and activated)
6. Finally restored IE settings through:
   Internet options -> Advanced -> Reset 
   (Note: I tried that before 1 week earlier, but then this DID NOT yield a solution either)
7. Eureka, it works again !

Result is now as follows using the Oracle-Java online test tool, and any Java-applets now work again in IE11:
"Gefeliciteerd!
U beschikt over de juiste Java-versie. (Version 8 Update 40)."

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue. Now it's solved. If someone is still having same kind of issue can give a try:

1. **Upgrade Java to latest version** (and uninstall all previous version of java)
2. Add the url to the **Exception site list** in your **Java Control Panel** [Follow Instruction Here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same problem for me, because I was running the last java version 1.8.0_92, IE v11 and windows 7.

My situation was also that I had **Chrome as the default browser**.

So what for me fixed it, was to set IExplorer as the default browser again, uninstall Java, go to Java.com using the IExplorer, and from the IExplorer download and install Java again to the last version.

Answer (score 0):

**Today**, I stuck with this error, and went through all the answers but nothing worked out for me.

For me the issue was `**Java version**`.

**Initially**, I installed `Java 8 Update 251 x64` which actually was the reason of my issue applet not working issue with `Internet Explorer version 11`.

**Solution**

Uninstalled `Java 8 Update 251 x64`

Installed `Java 8 Update 251 x86`

**issue resolved.**

Answer (score -1):

I had a REAL problem finding `jre 7u45` to download and re-install after `7u51` screwed up my Windows 7 system. I logged in to my Slackware Linux box and downloaded `jre 7u45` this way:

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" "https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jre-7u45-windows-x64.exe"

wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" "https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jre-7u45-windows-i586.exe"
```

Then I put the files on a USB stick and installed the x64 version on my Windows system.