# Why does Java 7 fail to Verify after successful JRE installation - Java 7 not running my any browser

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, verification

This question was dogging me for a few days until I found almost a full answer but I want to share the issue first:

**ISSUE**

I have a Windows 7 pro 64 bit laptop that supports both IPv4 and IPv6 (important later)
I downloaded and installed the latest Java 7 u 51 jre / browser plugin and would always get a grey applet box before it would eventually redirect and say "failed to verify" if java was installed.

I am also a java developer and had a few JDKs installed as well as jres.  Thinking it was my environment I did a complete wipe of jave from my system (I ran JavaRa and made sure everything was removed http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/)

I installed the 32 bit version of the JRE for the chrome plugin and made sure all the setting and security info was correct (per the many posts about this topic).

After clearing all cache (browser and java), punching holes through my firewall (even disabling it to see if that would resolve it) as well as running things as administrator, verifying java was installed and running in all my browsers (it failed in IE, Chrome and FF)

All of this was per many posts that said how to solve the issue of Java 7 not running in any browser.

After enabling full trace and debugging with the Java console via the Java Control Panel
I finally get some decent clues from the stack traces displayed in the console.  It was failing to get resources from java or any site that had an applet or jnlp web start file.

Comment: add your solution as an answer and accept it as an answer - so you'll get a better overview for other people...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Finally I ran across this post here (Java 7 on 32-bit Windows 7 - Java Webstart - Unable to load resource)

When adding "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" to the runtime parameters under the Java Control Panel (java tab, view) for the current JRE, it solved the problem. I was able to restore my security setting to proper levels and was able to run the java verification tests as well asa bunch of other applets just fine.

When it cam to running jnlp files, I would still get errors unless I manually edit the jnlp file and add it to the vm args i.e.

If you want to apply this change system wide, add the **_JAVA_OPTIONS** environment variable and add **-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true** to it

Regards, Shawn Recinto

Comment: Fixed the remaining issue too.... Added -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  to _JAVA_OPTIONS in my system environment variables and it works for all

Answer (score 0):

We are using Windows 8.1 and after updating to the newest java 7u51 we had the same problem and after tech service gave up on our problem, using your help, we found that there was a check box in the Java Control panel that said "Enable Java content in the browser" just needed to be checked. This apparently still needed to be done even though it had already been enabled in the internet settings 'manage add-ons'.

This check box was under the Security Tab in the Java Control Panel.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you guys!  This was one heck of a problem to deal with

Answer (score 0):

**If you have Chrome and 64-bit Windows** here is the answer ([originally found here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/gfsZW3XQOA0/0Iflk1-zuV0J)):

"... We all will just have to not use Chrome until they have another release or patch to fix the problem, or roll back Java to pre-7 versions.
"Chrome does not support Java 7. Java 7 runs only on 64-bit browsers and Chrome is a 32-bit browser.

If you download Java 7, you will not be able to run Java content in Chrome and will need to use a 64-bit browser (such as Safari or Firefox) to run Java content within a browser. Additionally, installing Java 7 will disable the ability to use Apple Java 6 on your system..."

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

This is a Java.net.SocketException, problem the first answer is correct but here is a very quick way of solving this problem in under a minute.

How to fix

1. Open command prompt (windows start button, type cmd in search)
2. Click top left of command prompt, click properties, enable quick edit mode
3. Copy: setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
4. Right click on command prompt, should paste
5. Hit enter. That easy!

After following these steps you applets/java applications should run well and correctly.Refer to this site youtube video for visual presentation.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=serdRSsl5wE

Answer (score 0):

This is a `Java.net.SocketException`, problem the first answer is correct but here is a very quick way of solving this problem in under a minute:

```
Open command prompt (windows start button, type cmd in search)
Click top left of command prompt, click properties, enable quick edit mode
Copy: setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Right click on command prompt, should paste
Hit enter. That easy!
```

After following these steps you applets/java applications should run well and correctly.Refer to this site youtube video for visual presentation.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=serdRSsl5wE