# HTML button onClick not launching Applet

Tags: java, html, applet

I have an Applet program, which works fine in Eclipse. I want to load this applet when I click on a button action from a html code. I have kept the html file in the same path where I have this applet class. I am just testing now, so haven't hosted this html file in server, before that I want to test this is working.

I searched forums and trying like below, but I couldn't get it working as expected. Applet is not launching on click button event. I am missing something, could someone guide me to make this working?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Welcome on board! </TITLE>
    <script>
        function loadApplet()
        {
            var appletbox=document.getElementById('MyApplet.class');

        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <p>Click here for new Applet session!</p>
    <button onclick="loadApplet">Click here</button>

</BODY>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Welcome on board! </TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadApplet()
        {
        alert("Load Applet");
        document.write("<applet code='MyApplet' height='300' width='300'></applet>");
        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <p>Click here for new Applet session!</p>
    <button onclick="loadApplet();">Click here</button>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have tested on my machine and it is working

Comment: Yes, Its working thank you. Can I open the applet in new window instead of running on the same web page?

Comment: I think it is not possible, but you can search for it. And mark my answer as Accpted, when you get the time

Comment: I see document.write is for writing string based on this reference http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write  But, I want to applet to be running when clicking on "Click here" button, as the Applet does different functionality later like connecting with another socket program etc.

Comment: Applet functionality is independent of What you are writing in document.write.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `()` for your function here, so you can use:

```
<button onclick="loadApplet()">Click here</button>
```

instead of:

```
<button onclick="loadApplet">Click here</button>
```

Comment: its not launching the applet.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add brackets

Try this:

```
 <button onclick="loadApplet()">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Still ,its not launching the applet.

Answer (score 0):

You are including your applet in wrong way. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145293/can-not-run-java-applets-in-internet-explorer-11-using-jre-7u51/21375547#21375547) on other question.
You should use `<applet>`, `<object>` or `<embed>` tag to include applet on your page. This starts applet automatically, but when you use [my method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145293/can-not-run-java-applets-in-internet-explorer-11-using-jre-7u51/21375547#21375547) you can append applet to page clicking the button. In function `loadApplet` use code similar to my code.

On your page there is no element with id `MyApplet.class`, so you can't get this element by id.