# why is the message showed "To view the content on this page,Please click here to install JAVA"?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

we are developing an JavaFX application.
i'd like to start this application by web start throu WebSite, but the message("To view  the content on this page,please click here to install Java") is showed.
So, i cannot start this application. what should i do??

could you give us any hints!!

FYI,we can start the application using NetBeans(debugging mode & normal mode).
of course, we checked that Java was installed.

(Application Development Environment)
OS:Windows7 64bit ver6.1

Browser:IE11

JDK:JDK1.7.0_40

Language:JavaFX2.2.40

Tool:NetBeans IDE7.3.1

Comment: Follow the instructions and install JRE. It looks like JRE is missing on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 is not a [supported browser for JavaFX 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html), so Oracle haven't validated that JavaFX will work with it.

Some browsers run in 32 bit mode, so they don't work with 64 bit Java, perhaps this is the issue here, or perhaps Oracle don't have a compatible 64 bit plugin for Internet Explorer 11.

Additional issues are the JavaFX deployment toolkit might not understand the Internet Explorer 11 user agent string (as detailed in [JavaFx web not working with Internet Explorer 11 with JRE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136098/javafx-web-not-working-with-internet-explorer-11-with-jre7)).

There are further issues detailed and potential fixes for them detailed in the answers and comments on [Can not run Java Applets in Internet Explorer 11 using JRE 7u51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145293/can-not-run-java-applets-in-internet-explorer-11-using-jre-7u51).

JDK1.7.0_40 is not the most recent version of Java.  If you must run Java in a browser, *always* require the most recent version, otherwise you open your clients up to potential security compromises.  Additionally, earlier Java versions are probably less likely to be compatible with later browser versions.

Comment: Hi,jewelsea. Thank you for your corporation.
We need to learn more about JavaFX.
After check your advice, we conciderd that this app worked on Chrome.
So we try to use otehr browser. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This messgae is shown when `JRE is not installed` or `multiple versions of JRE is installed` in the same machine. Please check your java version in the console. Try to uninstall the JDK(s) installed in your machine and reinstall the latest !

Comment: @hiro hope it helps !

Comment: hi,ItachiUchiha. thank you for your answer.

however,unfortunatelly,we already have checked that JRE is installed and not multiple vrsion of JRE.

and JRE Version of WebServer and client are same versions...